# how to start django shell with ipython in qtconsole mode?

Tags: python, django, shell, ipython

When i start django shell by typing `python manage.py shell` 
the [ipython](http://ipython.org/) shell is started. Is it possible to make Django start ipython in [qtconsole](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html) mode? (i.e. make it run `ipython qtconsole`)

Arek

edit:
so I'm trying what Andrew Wilkinson suggested in his answer - extending my django app with a command which is based on original django shell command. As far as I understand code which starts ipython in original version is this:

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    requires_model_validation = False

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        from IPython.frontend.terminal.embed import TerminalInteractiveShell
        shell = TerminalInteractiveShell()
        shell.mainloop()
```

any advice how to change this code to start ipython in qtconsole mode?

second edit:
what i found and works so far is - start 'ipython qtconsole' from the location where settings.py of my project is (or set the sys.path if starting from different location), and then execute this:

```
import settings
import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)
```

and now can i import my models, list all instances etc.

Comment: There may not be a simple command for it yet, but it certainly should be possible to make that work.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to you, if you were to alias `ipython` to `ipython qtconsole` in `/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: @Unapiedra: I don't think that would work. Django starts ipython by importing and calling it at a Python level, not using a shell command.

Comment: @Unapiedra : would u mind telling me how to do it, i usually make an alias using .bashrc, not sure how to alias file

Comment: @ThomasK: Okay, I wasn't sure how it does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a shell script with the following:

```
/path/to/ipython
qtconsole --pylab inline -c "run /path/to/my/site/shell.py"
```

You only need the `--pylab inline` part if you want the cool inline matplotlib graphs.

And I created a python script `shell.py` in `/path/to/my/site` with:

```
import os
working_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(working_dir)
import settings
import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)
```

Running my shell script gets me an ipython qtconsole with the benefits of the django shell.

Comment: After a new installation of ipython this isn't working for me anymore.  ipython qtconsole seems to not be honoring the -c flag anymore.  I've switched to Thomas K's answer.

Answer (score 7):

The docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) say:

> If you'd rather not use manage.py, no problem. Just set the
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to mysite.settings and run
>   python from the same directory manage.py is in (or ensure that
>   directory is on the Python path, so that import mysite works).

So it should be enough to set that environment variable and then run `ipython qtconsole`. You could make a simple script to do this for you automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7866515/213118, so u have to add your django project location to path as well, and still django had some problem with settings - when i wanted list all objects in my model it said i haven't set the db engine

Answer (score 2):

You can check the code that runs the shell [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/shell.py). You'll see that there is no where to configure what shell is run.

What you could do is copy this file, rename it as shell_qt.py and place it in your own project's management/commands directory. Change it to run the QT console and then you can run `manage.py shell_qt`.

Comment: and how can i change the code to run qt console - could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Since Django version 1.4, usage of `django.core.management.setup_environ()` is deprecated. A solution that works for both the IPython notebook and the QTconsole is this (just execute this from within your Django project directory):

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: from mydjangoproject.settings import DATABASES as MYDATABASES

In [3]: settings.configure(DATABASES=MYDATABASES)
```

**Update:** If you work with Django 1.7, you additionally need to execute the following:

```
In [4]: import django; django.setup()
```

Using [`django.conf.settings.configure()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#django.conf.settings.configure), you specify the database settings of your project and then you can access all your models in the usual way.

If you want to automate these imports, you can e.g. create an IPython profile by running:

```
ipython profile create mydjangoproject
```

Each profile contains a directory called `startup`. You can put arbitrary Python scripts in there and they will be executed just after IPython has started. In this example, you find it under

```
~/.ipython/profile_<mydjangoproject>/startup/
```

Just put a script in there which contains the code shown above, probably enclosed by a `try..except` clause to handle `ImportError`s. You can then start IPython with the given profile like this:

```
ipython qtconsole --profile=mydjangoproject
```

or

```
ipython notebook --profile=mydjangoproject
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to open the Django shell in qtconsole. Looking inside manage.py solve the problem for me:
Launch IPython qtconsole, cd to the project base directory and run:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
```

Dont forget to change 'myproject' to your project name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command that extends the base shell command and imports the IPythonQtConsoleApp like so:

create file qtshell.py in yourapp/management/commands with:

```
from django.core.management.commands import shell

class Command(shell.Command):
    def _ipython(self):
        """Start IPython Qt console"""
        from IPython.qt.console.qtconsoleapp import IPythonQtConsoleApp
        app = IPythonQtConsoleApp.instance()
        app.initialize(argv=[])
        app.start()
```

then just use `python manage.py qtshell`

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat undocumented feature of `shell_plus` is the ability to run it in "kernel only mode". This allows us to connect to it from another shell, such as one running qtconsole.

For example, in one shell do:

```
django-admin shell_plus --kernel
# or == ./manage.py shell_plus --kernel
```

This will print out something like:

> ```
> # Shell Plus imports ...
> ...
>
> To connect another client to this kernel, use:
>    --existing kernel-23600.json
> ```

Then, in another shell run:

```
ipython qtconsole --existing kernel-23600.json
```

This should now open a QtConsole. One other tip, instead of running another shell, you can also hit <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, and run `bg` to tell current process to run in background.

Answer (score -1):

You can install [django extensions](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/index.html) and then run

```
python manage.py shell_plus --ipython
```

Comment: -1. This command simply starts IPython in the terminal with all models preloaded. It does not start IPython in qtconsole mode. So this is not a correct answer for this question.