# Django 1.4 on GAE: sqlite "ImportError: cannot import name utils"

Tags: django, google-app-engine, sqlite, django-1.4

I'm trying to get sqlite3 support working on Django 1.4 on Google App Engine 1.7.4 on Python 2.7.

I fiddled around with the "Google Cloud SQL" database backend, all worked well (syncdb, insert/update/delete, ...).

But then I enabled sqlite (as Google Cloud SQL is slow when on localhost):

```
import os
if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine') or
    os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'pushtolive'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms',
            'INSTANCE': 'xyz:xyz',
            'NAME': 'my_database',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running in development, so use a local SQLite database
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': '/tmp/mysite.db',
        }
    }
```

and when I open any url (e.g. 127.0.0.1:8080) then I run into [this monstrous stack trace](https://gist.github.com/raw/4405464/76f6a6c31fb56d54bc8e9668ddea40d508ea714c/sqlite.traceback). I stripped down the stack trace so it's more readable:

```
ERROR    2012-12-29 09:07:06,223 base.py:215] Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/philipp/python/mysite/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib import admin
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File ".../google_appengine/lib/django_1_4/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.db import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

From the stack trace I read that the execution runs to the `django.db.utils` module, then into `django.db.backends.sqlite3.base`, then it tries to jump into `django.db.utils` again but that then strangely fails.

The problem seems to be in the GAE environment, since this works:

```
python mysite/manage.py syncdb
```

And this as well:

```
python mysite/manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User(username="hans")
>>> u.save()
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: hans>]
```

**What I tried so far:**

- switched from/to Django 1.3/1.4
- [uninstalled GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189054/how-do-i-uninstall-google-app-engine-sdk#answer-14081488), installed it again
- I tried through all the solutions google reveals for "ImportError from django.db import utils"
- there is [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866256). I tried executing the statements in the question and I don't run into the problem.

I'm on OS X 10.8.2
My PYTHONPATH is `:/usr/local/google_appengine:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django_1_4`

Comment: I suggest you make your edit into an answer (where you explain that it's not a good idea), and choose that.

Comment: just saw this after you added your comment - had the same idea :-)

Comment: why did you remove your answer?

Comment: Because it was Datastore-centric and misleading.  I was starting to attract the downvoters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's [not good practice to use sqlite in dev and mysql (as used by Cloud SQL) in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306048/django-sqlite-for-dev-mysql-for-prod) I don't recommend this setup to anyone.

Then, there is the option `--use_sqlite`: This is used to speed up development when using the Google Data*store*. There is no similar option for Cloud SQL.

Comment: +1 for coming back and informing anyone else with this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This can be resolved by whitelisting the sqlite3 module by appending `_sqlite3` to `_WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES` in `/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py`.

Note, you'll need to have selected "Make Symlinks..." in the app engine launcher to to access the file from `/usr/local`.

Comment: cheers mate, I had this issue and I actually thought I should ask you how to solve it. Bogdan :)

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of the SDK, you can enable the sqlite3 module in the sandbox by adding

```
'sqlite3' in name.lower()
```

in the _should_keep_module function in google-app-engine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py (around line 195)