# Django cannot import name utils

Tags: django, apache

If I run python manage.py runserver, it works fine. But when I try to have my site run through apache, I keep getting the error:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=25005): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/apps/peer-web/peer_web/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.auth.middleware: "datetime initialization failed"
 mod_wsgi (pid=25005): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/apps/peer-web/peer_web/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.auth.middleware: "cannot import name utils"
```

**EDIT**: new traceback after re-installing Django

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=25005): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/apps/peer-web/peer_web/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.auth.middleware: "cannot import name utils"
 mod_wsgi (pid=25005): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/apps/peer-web/peer_web/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/apps/peer-web-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.auth.middleware: "cannot import name utils"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16136 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866256/django-circular-import-error

Comment: Both of them relate to a import of a db, which is different from mine.

Comment: You setup is not using the same version of django as what you have developed. Check virtual environment setup and Python paths.

Comment: Both environments are using Django 1.5.1

Comment: You need to reinstall django. Something is corrupted in your environment.

Comment: After reinstalling the `datetime initialization failed` disappeared, but the `cannot import name utils` is still present. And is repeated twice

Comment: Had the same error "cannot import name utils" intermittantly when I had this in middleware: 'privateviews.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware', and system had logged me out.  Logging in and out fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm using an Amazon Linux EC2 Instance, I forgot that installing `mod_wsgi` from the package installer will be configured using `python2.6`. So after reinstalling `mod_wsgi` using `python2.7`, it fixed my problem.

**EDIT:**

To configure it with `python2.7`, inside the `mod_wsgi` source folder I did the following:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7
make install
```

Comment: How exactly did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure both the **project path and site-packages** for your virtual environment are added to your mod_wsgi configuration.

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python2.X/site-packages
```

[Django docs for deploying using mod_wsgi and a virtualenv](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv)

Comment: Both are in the python path

Comment: Could you add your Apache config and `wsgi.py` to the question please?